# Autofac and MVC4 issue when resolving -> please check my code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, generics, repository, autofac, resolve

I am using Autofac with MVC4 but somehow when trying to resolve it fails. I don't get any error during the registerations. The code looks like this:

```
    public void Register()
    {
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("KidsWear.DataLayer"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("KidsWear.Repositories"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("KidsWear.Contexts"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load("KidsWear.Entities"));
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray()).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterControllers();
        //builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();
        // test -> isRegistered  returns fals
        var isRegistered = container.IsRegistered(typeof(IProductRepository));
        // This line raises error: The requested service //KidsWear.Repositories.IProductRepository' has not been registered. 
        var concrete = container.Resolve<IProductRepository>();
        // End test
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

I have all my interfaces inside "KidsWear.Repositories", the actual implementation is inside "KidsWear.DataLayer", "KidsWear.Contexts" has the Generic repository and Context. ProductRepository Interface looks as below:

```
public interface IProductRepository : IGenericRepository<Product>
{

}
```

Product repository is inheriting from GenericRepository and IProductRepository like this:

```
public class ProductRepository : GenericRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    public ProductRepository()
    {

    }

    //Todo: add any extra subs specific to Product
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this registration does not work and what this error is? Just in debug mode if I hover on container, I can see that it has been initialised.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact code worked perfectly fine. Not actually sure what the problem was. Not sure if Visual Studio needed a restart or Autofac was playing badly!!!